# Connection refused when trying connecting to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, materialized

#Edit
Sorry its not connect to PostgreSQL but im trying to connect to materialized shell but it's getting an error like below

```
 psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 6875?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 6875?
```

how can i solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Port `6875` seems a strange number for a Postgres server, its default port is `5432`. Are you sure you are using the correct port number? If you know you are is the Postgres server actually up and running? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Is the materialize docker instance actually running?